# how can i get the Words in the Tool Tips By Using the Selenium WebDriver in the TestNg Class

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to display the Words, Which are available in the Tool Tips.

For Example i have an Image where we can see the Tool Tip, that Tool Tip is showing the Word as `apsadmin`.

That Word need to display as output in by Console.. So, can anyone let me know the solution?

Comment: The image is missing, which leaves your question far to vague. Also avoid messages like "please reply it's urgent", this is a community question/answer website, not hotline.

Answer (score 0):

The Text in ToolTip will be placed in `title` attribute.
If your element is inside a `input` tag, below is the Webdriver code to read and display the tooltip.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("input"));
String title = element.getAttribute("title");
System.out.println(title);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will want to hover over the object first to display the tool tip.

This can be achieved by using the Actions class. [javadocs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('header')/h1/a"));     
String toolTipText = element.getAttribute("title");
System.out.println("Tool tip text present :- " +toolTipText);
```